# Can GitHub be used for writing a collaborative article?

Tags: github, collaboration

I am contemplating writing a useful article in a field of my interest. There are many others (about 10-15) people interested in peer reviewing and collaborating on the same. I am not a prolific programmer, but I understand how [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) works for version control.

Can I use it for writing a 4-5 page collaborative article (version control is very important part) or do you think a better alternative exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You certainly could, but I don't know if it's the best choice. A couple of questions come to mind. Is this a text-based document format or are you planning on doing your writing in something like MS Word? If the former then I think it could work well. If the latter I would say it may be less effective.

What about your other collaborators? Are they savvy enough to use a DVCS? That would have some influence as well. I don't know how strongly you need the document versioned, but I could see using git as overkill.

I've found that using Google Docs works well and has a revision history, although it's obviously not as robust as would be found in a VCS.

Comment: Thanks , actually the initial article will be a text based one ...but the option to add a few figures and tables would have been helpful

Answer (score 4):

I think it would work great. The [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are on a publicly write/readable [repository at GitHub](https://github.com/lifo/docrails), for instance. You get get [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) things for free (*branches*, blame, general version control features), plus you'll have a reliable backup and publishing mechanism if you like.

Given that the contributers are computer literate enough to successfully use Git, that is.

If you write it in [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), you can throw inline [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) into it (just by itself like you can do on Stack Overflow). Easy to write, easy to style, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but on the other hand:

Most wikis allow rich-content pages **easyly**, are ready for collaborative editing and have versioning and version-management embedded in the core.

Comment: What you mean under "architecture like github" term?

Comment: @user2760 Cloning of what? The whole wiki? For which reason? One article? Templates in wikis, which have it. Undo to *any previous* version - is a **core** of anywiki

Comment: yes but every user with his or her own copy ?..as far as i understand wiki you cannot have multiple copies , you edit one and different versions exist (undo based) but not for individual edits made by different users

Comment: @user2760 - you have **one site** with **one wiki**, which show **latest version** of each article (page) - see at Wikipedia at least

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9067/discussion-between-user2760-and-lazy-badger)

Answer (score 1):

One promissing recent development is penflip (https://www.penflip.com/) which was created with the idea of being a "github for text".

Check this article to learn about the author's ideas http://madebyloren.com/github-for-writers

Answer (score 0):

Consider using google docs. They have some kind of version control. And it is much more suitable for this kind of work.